# Is there any way to pass cookie to IWebBrowser2 navigate

Tags: c++, winapi, cookies, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

Is there any way to pass cookie to IWebBrowser's Navigate method.

As far as I can see neither passing Cookie header in headers nor InternetSetCookie/InternetSetCookieEx works with IE11.

The only working method I found is to set cookie via put_cookie of IHTMLDocument2, but for that you have to load page first.

Is there any way to pass cookie to first call of Navigate?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`IESetProtectedModeCookie`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197007(VS.85).aspx) if you are interacting with low-integrity browser controls. This still has limitations as noted in [this cookie FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/20/internet-explorer-cookie-internals-faq/):

> IE10+ on Windows 8+ introduced Enhanced Protected Mode which uses
>   AppContainers (rather than Integrity Levels) for isolation. EPM does
>   not offer an API for interacting with cookies;
>   IESetProtectedModeCookie will not set the cookie inside an
>   AppContainer.

Creating AppContainers is not documented so I assume your process is not running in a AppContainer?

[This newsgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/microsoft.public.windows.inetexplorer.ie5.programming.components.webbrowser_ctl/cvFWvJXfvjQ) confirms that you cannot set a cookie in the headers:

> In case anybody is interested, I went through Microsoft support to
>   find out more about this. Their answer: what I want to do is not
>   supported.  The 'headers' argument to Navigate/Navigate2 CANNOT be
>   used to set cookies.

I'm guessing that refreshing the page after `put_cookie` is unacceptable?

Comment: Your link states that IESetProtectedModeCookie - Calls the standard InternetSetCookieEx, so I don't think that'll make a difference to direct call.

Comment: > I'm guessing that refreshing the page after put_cookie is unacceptable?


Right now I do exactly that, but that's undesirable.

Comment: IESetProtectedModeCookie calls InternetSetCookieEx in the right context. You have not provided any information about your application so I don't know if it is relevant but on Vista+ IE has two storage locations for cookies.

Comment: I simply create instance of IE via CoCreateInstance and use Navigate to go to page via automation. And I want to set cookie in http request passed by Navigate. IESetProtectedModeCookie doesn't help either.